# Why casperjs aborted silently with invalid javascript code？

Tags: javascript, casperjs

This is what I've tried:

```
[roxma@localhost test]$ cat invalid.js
"use strict";

var casper = require('casper').create({});

// missing ;
var aa

casper.run();
[roxma@localhost test]$ casperjs invalid.js
[roxma@localhost test]$
```

I have no idea why caspers aborted silently. I would expected some hint on the error.

```
casperjs --version
1.1.3
phantomjs -v
2.1.1
```

=====================

#### Edit

Sorry, my mistake. The previous example is not an error.

The following example is closer to the situation I encountered.

```
"use strict";
var casper = require('casper').create({});

casper.start('http://www.qq.com/');

casper.then(function() {
        this.echo('begin');
        var a;
        var b = {
                a: a['d']
        };
        this.echo('end');
});

casper.run();

[roxma@localhost test]$ casperjs  invalid.js
begin
[roxma@localhost test]$
```

Comment: There are no error in your script

Comment: @lgor     
There is a missing ';' after "var aa"

Comment: casperjs is not aborted, just exited. that's not an error: [7.9.1 Rules of Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9.1)

Comment: @lgor Oh, my mistake. I've add another more appropriate example now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `casper.on('error')` callback, in order to catch the error, like so:

```
"use strict";
var casper = require('casper').create({
//    verbose: true,
//    logLevel: 'debug'
});
//casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {this.echo('The error from evaluate: ' + msg, "ERROR");});
casper.on('error', function(msg) {
    this.echo('Error: ' + msg, "ERROR");
})

casper.start('http://www.qq.com/',function() {
        this.echo('begin');
        var a;
        var b = { a: a['d'] };
        this.echo('end');
});
casper.run();
```